# CountIF to Count Cells Affected by Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, countif

After much research I have found nothing without VBA to count a range of cells that have been affected by conditional formatting (specifically are turned "red").

I know there is no way to count the "red" cells so I am going the route of creating a CountIF formula with the same criteria that is in the conditional formatting but i'm having issues creating the criteria.

I thought it would be simple and to just add "CountIF($G:$G," before the below code. This data is also inside a table named "TT".

[image]

```
=AND(OR(AND(TODAY()-$F1>1095,TODAY()-$G1>1095),$G1=0,AND($F1=0,TODAY()-$G1>1095)),$A1>0)
```

Comment: First step will be to rearrange your formula so that Cells are on one side of comparisons, and everything else is on the other - e.g. `Today()-$G1>1095` becomes `$G1 < Today()-1095`.  This way, your `COUNTIFS` conditions will be in the form `$G:$G, "<" & Today()-1095`

Comment: I would insert a helper column in front of after column G to identify the cells that triggered conditional formatting using the same criteria, and do a simple COUNTIF of that helper column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my own formula using the table headers and a combination of `SUM(` `COUNTIFS(` `COUNTBLANK(`. It's battle tested and works!

`=SUM(COUNTIFS(TT[Fiscal Law 301 CBT],"<"&TODAY()-1095,TT[Fiscal Law In-Residence],"<"&TODAY()-1095),COUNTBLANK(TT[Fiscal Law 301 CBT]),COUNTIFS(TT[Fiscal Law In-Residence],"",TT[Fiscal Law 301 CBT],"<"&TODAY()-1095))`

Answer (score 1):

The `OR` makes things slightly mode complicated - you need to add the `COUNTIFS`, and then subtract when both are true (to prevent double-counting),  To demonstrate, if we want where `Column A = 0` or `Column B = 0`:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A, 0) + COUNTIF(B:B, 0) - COUNTIFS(A:A, 0, B:B, 0)
```

Except, you seem to be doing this with 3 conditions, which makes it bigger (add individual, subtract where 2 match, then *add* where all 3 match) - but there's actually a trick here, which I'll get to later.

To make it easier, we can rewrite your conditions from format `Value - A1 > Const` to `A1 < Value - Const`.  This means the `COUNTIF` would be `Countif(A:A, "<" & Value - Const)`

```
=AND(OR(AND($F1<TODAY()-1095,$G1<TODAY()-1095),$G1=0,AND($F1=0,$G1<TODAY()-1095)),$A1>0)
```

Now, let's split that out into our individual `COUNTIFS`.  There's the outer `AND`, so `$A1>0` is in all of them, then there's an `OR` with 3 conditions.  This gives us:

```
COUNTIFS($A:$A,">0", $G:$G, "<" & Today()-1095, $F:$F, "<" & Today()-1095)
COUNTIFS($A:$A,">0", $G:$G, 0)
COUNTIFS($A:$A,">0", $G:$G, "<" & Today()-1095, $F:$F, 0)
```

Now, here's the trick I mentioned earlier:  I don't know about you, but I can see some duplication going on here.  For example, the first and the third?  Column F is less than `Today()-1095`, OR Column F is 0.  Except, day 1095 is the 30<sup>th</sup> December 1902 - so `Today()-1095` will always be greater than 0.  Today, for example, it will be `42576`.  This means when the **third** condition is `True`, the **first** condition will also always be true.  So, we can ignore the third `COUNTIF` entirely!

Now, we can't do this with the first and second conditions - because if column F is greater than `Today()-1095` the first condition will always be `False`, but the **second** condition will be `True` *if* Column G is `0`

So, using our example from earlier, we have the following:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,">0", $G:$G, "<" & Today()-1095, $F:$F, "<" & Today()-1095)
+COUNTIFS($A:$A,">0", $G:$G, 0)
-COUNTIFS($A:$A,">0", $G:$G, 0, $G:$G, "<" & Today()-1095, $F:$F, "<" & Today()-1095)
```

But!  Look at that last `COUNTIFS`.  It has `G:G = 0` AND `G:G < Today()-1095`.  But, if Column G is 0, then it is *also* less than `Today()-1095` (Disclaimer:  On-or-after New Year's Eve 1902)  So, we can simplify that:

```
-COUNTIFS($A:$A,">0", $G:$G, 0, $F:$F, "<" & Today()-1095)
```

Which means our entire equation is as follows:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,">0", $G:$G, "<" & Today()-1095, $F:$F, "<" & Today()-1095)+COUNTIFS($A:$A,">0", $G:$G, 0)-COUNTIFS($A:$A,">0", $G:$G, 0, $F:$F, "<" & Today()-1095)
```

Comment: I plugged your last formula in and I got "0" so i assume something is wrong. I've spent about the last hour trying to decipher and correct any potential errors but am not having any luck. I have been able to build 3 seperate formulas, like you did, to meet the conditions but when adding them all together with the "+" or `SUM(` it only adds the first `COUNTIFS`. I do have a "DATA" page, would it be easier to insert a small chart to track these 3 conditions and have a simple `SUM(` to add the three cells?